# Should we nuke [fastboot] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I see that [fastboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastboot) tag questions are nothing about programming. I believe that OP should ask these questions on android.stackexchange.com. They may get better answer there.

Should we nuke [fastboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastboot) ?

Comment: Looks like a good burninate target to me. Summary doesn't have usage, info wiki seems like a copy-paste dump from somewhere, definitely doesn't sound like a tool you can *program with* in any way, and only 85 questions (most/all of which are tagged with other things).